# .NET WinForms DataGridView C# SortCompare apparently ignoring results

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have tried to implement a generic SortCompare event handler for use on any column on my (unbound) DataGridView control. All cell data are written as strings, but in reality some of them are used as integers (i.e. int.TryParse will return true). The intention is that if data are found to be integers then they will be compared as integers, otherwise a string compare will be used as a fallback.

The problem is that on one particular column, in which all cells' data are either empty strings or strings castable to int, the results appear to have been sorted as strings (e.g. "13", "135", "1350", "14", "149", "15") and not as integers (e.g. 13, 14, 15, 135, 149, 1350). Bizarre.

Here is my event handler (C#):

```
    private void DataGridView_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e)
    {
        var cell1 = e.CellValue1.ToString();
        var cell2 = e.CellValue2.ToString();

        if (cell1 == cell2)
        {
            e.SortResult = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (cell1 == "")
        {
            e.SortResult = -1;
            return;
        }

        if (cell2 == "")
        {
            e.SortResult = 1;
            return;
        }

        int value1, value2;
        if (int.TryParse(cell1, out value1) && int.TryParse(cell2, out value2))
            e.SortResult = value1 - value2; // Integer comparison
        else
            e.SortResult = string.Compare(cell1, cell2, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // String comparison
    }
```

I can verify that the line commented "Integer comparison" is hit multiple times, and the line commented "String comparison" is never hit. There doesn't appear to be any problem with the event handler firing. No exceptions are thrown. The column's SortMode is Automatic. It's just the results appear to have been string sorted.

Maybe something is not configured right in my DataGridView?

Comment: Not bizarre.  Strings are not numbers.  When you try to sort numbers as strings you get a lexical comparison where `"9"` will sort higher than `"100"` because `"9"` > `"1"`.  There are several good natural sort methods here but trying to compare numbers as strings is not a good idea to start with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the sort is reverting to the string compare AFTER your int comparison is made. Your code works as expected if you indicate that the event has been handled with the `e.Handled = true;` line. Have you tried adding the line `e.Handled = true;` to the end of your code?

The code below checks to see if the column to sort by is a number column. If it is then sort by the number, otherwise, sort by a string value. Hope this helps.

```
private void dataGridView1_SortCompare(object sender, DataGridViewSortCompareEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Column.Name == "NumberColumn") {
    if (int.TryParse(e.CellValue1.ToString(), out int value1) && int.TryParse(e.CellValue2.ToString(), out int value2)) {
      e.SortResult = value1.CompareTo(value2);
      e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Also as a side note, it appears you have named your `DataGridView` “DataGridView”… this is NOT a good idea.

Comment: Bingo! All it needed was "e.Handled = true;" Thanks a million!